# Data structure of the Breeze's entity manager cache

Tags: breeze

Is the data structure of the entity manager cache a collection of arrays of each entity type with the overall cache treated as simplified relational database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly, it is actually a lazy collection of sparse arrays (to allow for removal of detached entities), one per realized entity type with each array paired with an primary key index.

Comment: As I understand your response, the arrays are linked together in a hierarchical structure, but not the individual entities.

Comment: No the arrays are not linked together. But relationships between entities are all "live", meaning that as new entities are added to the cache all of the relationships between the entities are immediately resolved. So every entity always has all of its links to its related entities in the cache fully resolved.

Comment: Is that relationship information contained in the ComplexAspect class? If you have Customer, Order, Order Details tables, can you load them separately and in any order and will Breeze recalculate the parent, parentProperty and propertyPath as each table is loaded? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, if Customer, Order and OrderDetails are "entityTypes", no if they are "complexTypes".  ComplexTypes do not have identity that only occur as constituant parts of an entity.